# How to call a function from an extension in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the INSPhotoGallery framework(https://github.com/inspace-io/INSPhotoGallery), which is a photo gallery framework. I want to call a specific method on start, effectively making a preview on start rather than the overview / table view. I'd like to display the first cell preview image (which is displayed when you click on it).

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  INSPhotoGallery
//
//  Created by Michal Zaborowski on 04.04.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Inspace Labs Sp z o. o. Spółka Komandytowa. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import INSPhotoGalleryFramework

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var useCustomOverlay = false



    lazy var photos: [INSPhotoViewable] = {
        return [
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/JXY2d4A.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/JXY2d4A.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/NC4bqLB.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/NC4bqLB.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/jBbQXNz.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/jBbQXNz.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/WCXkdwW.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/WCXkdwW.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/p7ujK0t.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/p7ujK0t.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/Ak4qwsS.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/Ak4qwsS.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w2JJtDf.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w2JJtDf.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/HCCSco3.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/HCCSco3.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/Za6Ialf.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/Za6Ialf.jpg")),

            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/Pqc6k4v.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/Pqc6k4v.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/D8BBMd4.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/D8BBMd4.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/bggxrss.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/bggxrss.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w1Lnl2c.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w1Lnl2c.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/qoA0qA9.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/qoA0qA9.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/DkCEfkw.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/DkCEfkw.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/U4ihOo6.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/U4ihOo6.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/QvLBs7A.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/QvLBs7A.jpg")),
            INSPhoto(imageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/ZytdIk1.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/ZytdIk1.jpg")),

        ]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        for photo in photos {
            if let photo = photo as? INSPhoto {
                photo.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Note: Click top right to download wallpaper, \nscroll left or right to browse", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
            }
        }


    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ExampleCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExampleCollectionViewCell
        cell.populateWithPhoto(photos[indexPath.row])



        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photos.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ExampleCollectionViewCell
        let currentPhoto = photos[indexPath.row]
        let galleryPreview = INSPhotosViewController(photos: photos, initialPhoto: currentPhoto, referenceView: cell)
        if useCustomOverlay {
            galleryPreview.overlayView = CustomOverlayView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        }

        galleryPreview.referenceViewForPhotoWhenDismissingHandler = { [weak self] photo in
            if let index = self?.photos.indexOf({$0 === photo}) {
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
                return collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ExampleCollectionViewCell
            }
            return nil
        }
```

this one:

```
presentViewController(galleryPreview, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to be what's being asked. The `self` variable is available in extensions, so you can call most functions that would be available in an instance method.

Comment: How would I create a cell instance so that I could call the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can present it in `viewDidAppear`. For example:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0))
    let currentPhoto = photos.first!
    let galleryPreview = INSPhotosViewController(photos: photos \* if you only want to swipe the first image replace"photos" with "[photos.first!]", initialPhoto: currentPhoto, referenceView: cell)

    galleryPreview.referenceViewForPhotoWhenDismissingHandler = { [weak self] photo in
        if let index = self?.photos.indexOf({$0 === photo}) {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
            return self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        }
        return nil
    }
    self.presentViewController(galleryPreview, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Was this not working for you?

Comment: hello, is there a way that i can call this method into objective C code. I generated swift header. But can not find a way to call method inside extension